# jQuery .append this on hover

Tags: jquery, this

I'm trying to show a "quick buy" icon on hover of "this" id/img.  I do NOT want this quick buy icon to show on ALL images, just the one which is hovered over.

So far I have this:

jQuery:

```
jQuery('#main_cat_prods').delegate('img', 'hover', function(){
   jQuery("#QuickBuyProdBox" ).append($(this).clone());
 });
```

HTML:

```
<div id="comp-imageprince" class="image" style="height: 260px;"> <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0"> <tbody> <tr> <td><a href="/dresses/mandy-strappy-bandeau-layered-bodycon-dress/invt/azz50430"> <div class="overDIV" style="display:none;position: absolute;right: 5px;"></div>

<div id="QuickBuyProdBox"><p>test</p></div>
```

However, this is completely wrong and is simply cloning the image after div id "QuickBuyProdBox".  I think I've misunderstood the use of clone here!  Also, this is triggering on both hover on and hover off, I need it only to work when the user hovers on, and then disappear when the user hovers off.

What I need it to do: On hover show div id "QuickBuyProdBox" on top of or after div id "comp-imageprince". Then I need the div to hide again once the user removes their cursor from the div.

Any advice?

Many thanks, 
Myles

RESOLVED USING THE FOLLOWING SOLUTION:

```
jQuery('#main_cat_prods').delegate('img', 'mouseenter', function(){
                var $skuID = this.src.match(/[a-z][a-z][a-z]\d\d\d\d\d/)[0];

            if ( !jQuery('#QuickBuyProdBox').length ) {
                jQuery(this).closest('.image').prepend('<div id="QuickBuyProdBox" style="width:50px; height:50px; position:absolute; background-color:red; cursor:pointer;">');
            };
                jQuery("#QuickBuyProdBox").click(function(){
                    jQuery.event.trigger('lightbox', $skuID);
                });
                jQuery('.image, #QuickBuyProdBox').mouseleave(function(){
                jQuery('#QuickBuyProdBox').remove();
            });
        });
```

Comment: Wouldn't "after" make more sense here?  Such as: $('#bla').after('<div id="space"></div>');

Comment: What is `img` and `#main_cat_prods`, why are you using the `hover` event (you shouldn't btw), is the element already there and you're just trying to toggle the visiblity, or do you need to insert it? What do you want to clone? None of this makes any sense to me!

Comment: Sorry, the question isn't very well worded.  main_cat_prods is pulled in from Locayta.  It contains an image.  There are main main_cat_prods on my page.  When a user hovers over one of these main_cat_prods, I want a div to show on top or after that main_cat_prods.  Not all of them.

Comment: But it's an ID, there can be only one ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is untested, but...

```
jQuery('#main_cat_prods img').hover {
    function() {
        jQuery( this ).append( jQuery('#QuickBuyProdBox').clone());
     }, function() {
        jQuery( this ).find('#QuickBuyProdBox').remove();
     }
 });
```

Hover events may not fire correctly on touchscreen devices, though. Not sure if that's a concern of yours in this case, but it's worth bearing in mind.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working either :/  I think I'll re-ask the question and close this one down.

Answer (score 1):

Use mouseenter instead of hover:

```
jQuery('#main_cat_prods').delegate('img', 'mouseenter mouseleave', function(event){
   jQuery(this).toggle( event.type === 'mouseenter' );   
   jQuery("#QuickBuyProdBox" ).append($(this).clone());
 });
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work.  It just clones all of my products AFTER the "test".  This is the wrong way round.  I want to MOVE test on top or after (not clone, that was my mistake) the main cat div, but only THIS main cat div (the one that is hovered) not ALL of them.

Comment: This just removes my product completely haha!  Thanks anyway man.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use CSS for that. It's really simple, and more reliable/faster.

Check my example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/rzVjW/3/

Generic HTML:

```
<div class="buy-box"></div>
<input type="button" class="buy-button" value="My Button"/>
```

Generic CSS:

```
.buy-box{
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #FF99D5;
    margin: 5px;
}

.buy-box + .buy-button{
    visibility: hidden;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.buy-box:hover + .buy-button{
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Comment: I don't have access to the HTML of the products since I'm using Locayta.  I need to do this with jQuery.  Thanks though!

Comment: Hi Ivan, this is not an acceptable answer for this instance and while it does work, it is essentially useless to me as each of the divs created by Locayta all have the same ID.  Also, there are many other things I need to do with jQuery such as firing a lightbox on click etc.  This again COULD be done with CSS, but good luck trying to pass a sku (product ID) into a JS lightbox with CSS.

Cheers

Comment: Considering the example you gave, this would work. If you prefer to use jQuery (CPU) to do the work... then good look. I might consider reading about good website guidelines: http://learn.shayhowe.com/advanced-html-css/